# Break cyclic dependency in order to use dependency injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I just started using [dagger 2](http://google.github.io/dagger/) and have not used any other dependency injection framework before. Now I'm stuck with a cyclic dependency and I don't know how to solve it properly. Consider the following example in a server application, which uses the [Reactor pattern](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpjslides/nio.pdf) with Java NIO:

I have a `Handler` object attached to a selection key that is executed when new information arrives on the network:

```
class Handler implements Runnable {
  Server server;
  Client client;

  public void run {
    // static factory method that eventually calls a method on server, passing in 'client' as argument
    Command.parse(input).execute(server, client); 

  }

  public void send(String string) {
    // enqueu string and inform reactor about interest in sending
  }
}
```

The `Client` class holds some state about the connected client. All connected Clients are managed in the `Server` class.

```
class Client {
  Handler h;

  public send(String response) {
    h.send(response);          
  }
}
```

When new input arrives, the Handler creates the `Command` objects, executes them on the server, and the server eventually will respond to the client.

So what I'm doing right now, is creating a `Client` object manually in `Handler`, passing in a `this` reference, in order to be able to send the response:

```
client = new Client(this);
```

So my question now is: Is something wrong with the design? Is it possible to decouple `Client` and `Handler`? Or should I just live with this and don't use dependency injection `everywhere`?

I appreciate your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that what I really was trying to solve was not breaking the dependency between `Client` and `Handler`, but to use dependency injection instead of the `new` operator.

The solution I was looking for: Inject a `ClientFactory` into the constructor of `Handler` and use `clientFactory.create(this)` to create a `Client` object instead. The brilliant library [AutoFactory](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory) allows you to create such a factory with a simple `@AutoFactory` annotation. The constructor of the created class is automatically annotated with `@Inject`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the client to be able to send a message back through handler, then the following can break your cycle:

```
// lives in a common package both classes access
public interface ResponseClass {
     public void sendSomeMessage(String message);
}

public class Handler { // handler can also implement ResponseClass directly but I prefer using an additional class for flexibility.
     public void whenYouCreateClient() {
         Client client = new Client(new HandlerWrapper(this)); 
     }

     public static class HandlerWrapper implements ResponseClass {
         private final Handler handler;

         public HandlerWrapper(Handler handler) { this.handler = handler; }

         public void sendSomeMessage(String message) {
             handler.send(message);
         }
     }

     public void send(String string) {
         // enqueu string and inform reactor about interest in sending
     }
}

public class Client {
    ResponseClass rc; // naming should be improved :)

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        rc.sendSomeMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Now runtime your classes are still tied together but as far as your design is concerned your Client is only attached to a generic ResponseClass.

you can have a hierarchy like:

common <-- client <-- handler

where handler knows of client and common
and client only knows of common. (assuming you put the interface in the common package)

instead of
client <--> handler

I deliberately used sendSomeMessage to highlight that it's a different method you call ont he wrapper/interface but ofcourse you can name them however you like.

One remark: I didn't use dagger2 so I cannot say for sure that what I do can be done using that product, but this is how I would decouple this sort of cyclic dependency

Comment: If I got it correctly, I would still need to construct the Client object in my Handler object and pass in a reference to myself (`new Client(new HandlerWrapper(this))`). I'm new to the dependency injection thing, but if I understood it right, you should never use the `new` operator.

Comment: +1 for applying the [Interface_segregation_principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) also called [Inversion_of_control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Comment: @S1lentSt0rm: In order to make `Client` and `Handler` not dependant on the DI-Library, all construction of services and handlers should be done in one seperate wiring modul outside of the businesslogic

Comment: @k3b I think wiring them together somewhere else is what I need to do. The only public method in Handler _is_ `send(String s)`. The additional interface doesn't increase decoupling very much. Is the assumption correct that I can not do this with constructor injection but instead have to use method injection, because of the dependency between both?